# how to check repeated name in array?

Tags: javascript

i have two array containing different value as country name and its count from the database.

```
China3
Argentina3
Philippines2
Taiwan; Republic of China (ROC)2
Taiwan; Republic of China (ROC)2
Singapore2
Taiwan; Republic of China (ROC)2
Japan2
Singapore2
United States2
United States2
Chile2
Brazil2
Argentina2
Norway2
South Africa2
Dominican Republic2
United States2
Korea Republic of2
Lithuania2
China2
Israel2
Taiwan; Republic of China (ROC)2
Taiwan; Republic of China (ROC)2
Malaysia2
Latvia2
Hungary2
Israel2
Romania2
Italy2
Hungary2
Netherlands2
Russian Federation2
Singapore1
China1
```

i wanted to check for repeated name and add up its count value with this code

```
      var i ,rowcount;
      var suq = 0;
      var row =0;
      var check = 0;
      var number = 1;

        for (i = 0; i<count; i++){

        var countryname = countryarray[i];
        var hostcount = hosthitcount[i];

           for (rowcount=0;rowcount<number;rowcount++){
               //check for any repeated country name

             if (data.getValue(rowcount,0) == countryname ){

                           //get the hits                //rowindex
                  var pastvalue = data.getValue(rowcount,1);

                  //add the previous value with current value
                  var value = parseInt(hostcount)+parseInt(pastvalue);
                  value+= "";

                  //put it in the table
                  data.setValue(rowcount,1,value);
                  row++


             }else{
        data.setValue(suq, 0, countryname);
        data.setValue(suq, 1, hostcount);
        check++


        suq++;
             }//end of else

        }//second for loop
           }//first for loop
```

and the result shown only the first value in my array have add up but the other isnt
this is the result =

```
China6
Argentina3
Philippines2
Taiwan; Republic of China (ROC)2
Taiwan; Republic of China (ROC)2
Singapore2
Taiwan; Republic of China (ROC)2
Japan2
Singapore2
United States2
United States2
Chile2
Brazil2
Argentina2
Norway2
South Africa2
Dominican Republic2
United States2
Korea Republic of2
Lithuania2
Israel2
Taiwan; Republic of China (ROC)2
Taiwan; Republic of China (ROC)2
Malaysia2
Latvia2
Hungary2
Israel2
Romania2
Italy2
Hungary2
Netherlands2
Russian Federation2
Singapore1
nullnull
nullnull
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The Question is not really clear, i can see only one array, besides i would recommend you to extract the parsing and calculating ot the numbers behind the country name in a separated function, so you have separated search and find function and parse and calculate one.

Without understanding your code logic this line looks really wierd, maby its the reason that only one loop is executed which refers to the 1st country only:

```
for (rowcount=0;rowcount<number;rowcount++)
```

**number is set to 1**

Comment: sorry, what do you mean "behind the country name"? is the the code "var countryname = countryarray[i];" or? i tried to put number++ below the "data.setValue(rowcount,1,value)" but the result show blank.

Comment: I assumed your are parsing the numbers out of china1, china2 and china3 to get the china6, if its irrelevant please ignore this notice.

Comment: ya, i'm parsing the "numbers out of china1, china2 and china3 to get the china6".but is it possible to parse other country like Taiwan and other repeated country name. By the way "var countryname = countryarray[i];var hostcount = hosthitcount[i];" country name and host count come from individual array.sorry, my English are bad.